# Non-blocking echo of Java InputStream to OutputStream

Tags: java, tcp, stream, echo

It have established the following code, which seems to be working well:

```
void pipe(InputStream, OutputStream os) {
  try {
    try {
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024*16];
      int len, available = is.available();
      while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, available > 0 ? available : 1)) != -1) {
        os.write(buf, 0, len);
        available = is.available();
        if(available <= 0)
          os.flush();
      }
    } finally {
      try {
        os.flush();
      } finally {
        os.close();
      }
    }
  } finally {
    is.close();
  }
}
```

In the past, I found that if I call `is.read(buf)`, then, even if data was available, it would block waiting for more data until the buffer was full. This was an echo server for TCP data, so my requirement was for there to be an immediate flush as soon as new data was arrived.

My first solution was the inefficient one-at-a-time `is.read()`. Later, when that was not good enough, I was looking at the available methods and found `is.available()`. The API states:

> A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block.

So I have a pretty good solution now, but the one thing that looks bad to me is how I am handling cases where `is.available() == 0`. In this case, I simply read a single byte as a way to wait until new data is available.

---

What would be the recommended way to transfer data from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`, with immediate flush as data arrives? Is the above code really the right way, or should I change it, or use some brand new code? Perhaps I should be using some of the newer async routines, or maybe there is a built-in Java method for this?

Comment: "I found that if I call is.read(buf), then, even if data was available, it would block waiting for more data until the buffer was full" -- strange, because `InputStream` is explicitly documented to *not* wait until the buffer is full.

Comment: InputStream should wait for at least 1 byte, but it also should return as soon as some bytes are available.

Comment: Note that `os.flush()` will only flush Java's internal buffer to the OS buffer. To actually send the data over the wire you must activate the TCP_NODELAY option (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)

Comment: @parsifal & zhong, From [Java 6 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) *"The default implementation of this method blocks until the requested amount of input data len has been read, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown."* Therefore, the default implementation, and apparently other implementations as well, will sometimes wait until the buffer is full.

Comment: @jonnydee, I have found that calling `os.flush()` results in a seemingly immediate transmission of the data. This is acceptable for me.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey - you're confusing *normative* and *non-normative* documentation. *Normative* documentation is what's required; in this case, "An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read." *Non-normative* documentation describes how a particular implementation may diverge from the requirement, while still fulfilling this requirement. In this case, "The read(b, off, len) method for class InputStream simply calls the method read() repeatedly" and everything after that point.

Comment: To infer required behavior from non-normative documentation is a mistake.

Comment: @jonnydee That is not correct. The Nagle algorithm only delays packets, and by a small fraction of a second. It doesn't buffer them indefinitely as you imply.

Comment: @EJP Sorry my comment was not clear and that was not my desired implication. In the question there was the requirement of an _immediate_ flush. I wanted to note that the flush _might_ not be immediate without that option (despite being very fast for human perception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the past, I found that if I call is.read(buf), then, even if data was available, it would block waiting for more data until the buffer was full.

No you didn't. TCP doesn't work that way; sockets don't work that way; and Java sockets don't work that way. You are mistaken.

It's a lot simpler than you think:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

There is no buffering on socket input/output streams so this will write everything that's read as soon as it has been read.

Calling available() in this circumstance, or indeed almost any circumstance, is a complete waste of time.

This is also the way to copy any kind of input stream to any kind of output stream in Java.

If you want non-blocking code, use NIO. But I don't see that you really do.